# Boton "Siguiente" en navegador en android

Tags: javascript, html, android, chrome

En el navegador Chrome de android cuando el usuario ha hecho foco a un elemento `<input />` aparece un botón del teclado que dice **Siguiente** o en ocaciones dice **Ir** el problema es que no logro capturar el evento que este botón **Siguiente** genera, yo he intentado con el `keyCode` de tabulación pero aun así no funciona ¿Alguna idea de como resolverlo?

Comment: Lo que hace el "Siguiente" es cambiar el foco, el cambio de foco si es posible detectarlo con javaScript. Osea, para detectar el click necesitarías de alguna manera vincular un evento que ocurre en android con algo en js, pero lo que también puedes hacer es detectar el efecto que produce en javascript el click en "Siguiente".

Comment: Acostumbra agregar el código que hayas intentado o lo que investigaste, revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo el comentario, entiendo que la solución que estás buscando es precisamente la detección de un evento que ocurre en android que de alguna manera hay que vincularla con JavaScript. La forma de hacer eso parece ser usando [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html), como menciono en el comentario, lo que hace el "Siguiente" es cambiar el `focus()` del input y ese cambio si lo podemos detectar y manipular con JavaScrtipt, te dejo un ejemplo de lo que se podría hacer:

```js
[...document.getElementsByTagName("input")].forEach(element => {

  element.addEventListener("focus", (e) => {
  
    //e.preventDefault();//<-- Esto no funcionaría    
    //e.target.blur();//<-- Algo como esto si

    console.log("Cambió el foco al elemento con el id: "+e.target.id);

  });

})
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="input1" required type="text" /><br />
  <input id="input2" required type="text" /><br />
  <input id="input3" required type="text" /><br />
  <button type="submit">Enviar
  </button>
</form>
```

Obviamente, también se puede cambiar el focus programaticamente haciendo algo como `document.getElementById("input1").focus();`

Comment: Lo que pasa es que, en el navegador de escritorio si responde. Usando el keydown y su keycode. La funcion se ejecuta cuando el usuario oprime enter o tab. Pero en el mobil solo funciona enter cuando sale el boton **IR** pero cuando esta el boton **Siguiente** no ejecuta la funcion

Comment: En este caso no importa que presionen, importa que cosa esté en foco

Comment: @GabrielZapata Dicho en otras palabras, los listeners que usamos en este ejemplo son del focus, no de keypress, kedown o algún evento que realice el usuario, focus es un evento que ocurre en el elemento mismo, sin importar cómo se llegue a eso. De cualquier manera, la forma mas precisa sería usar webview al parecer.

Comment: Pero la cosa es que se supone que "Siguiente" su equivalente en ordenador sería "tab" pero no me responde el "keyCode" solo en ordenador